# Error in manifest - "Error parsing XML: unbound prefix"

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, xml-parsing

My manifest.xml is,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pilot.clicker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">


    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />
    <!-- Required -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>



    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar" >

        <meta-data android:name="com.revmob.app.id" android:value="52eb635c38a33"/>

        <activity android:name="com.revmob.ads.fullscreen.FullscreenActivity"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent"
              android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation">
        </activity>


         <activity
            android:name="com.pilot.clicker.Splash"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>



        <activity
            android:name="com.pilot.clicker.Main"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.pilot.clicker.MAINSCREEN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name="com.pilot.clicker.List"/>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

The error is being displayed after the first line. 
I'm attempting to integrate an ad-service 'Revmob' to my android-application. I've looked for an answer all over the internet..but just can't find a solution. Please help. 
Thank you.

Comment: remove the `package="com.pilot.clicker"` attribute from your manifest file and let us know if this solves the problem.

Comment: @John918 If you use eclipse, press **Project** in the Menu and then choose **Clean...**. Otherwise, just clean your project.

Comment: I think there is may be left space any where from starting tag of xmlns. So just format it by ctrl+shift+F

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put your uses-permission line after uses-sdk that is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.pilot.clicker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

 <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<!-- Required -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Also try to clean your project go to project menu (if you are using eclipse) and clean your project and re-run it. Might be this will resolve your issue.